# glog.Infoln not writing output to console

Tags: go, logging

I was using the WriteToConsole middleware to write the type of method called in the console. But glog.Infoln is not printing the information on the console...If i try glog.Errorln then it is  printing the information on the console.

main.go

```
func main() {
    // Create a new client and connect to the server
    client, err := database.GetConnection(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //Disconnect function to disconnect connection after the work is done
    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(context.TODO()); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()
    
    err=database.Ping(client,"demo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
    }

    flag.StringVar(&PORT, "port", "50080", "--port=50080 or -port=50080")
    flag.Parse()

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    srv := http.Server{
        Addr:         ":" + PORT,
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 15,
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 15,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Second * 60,
        Handler:      router, // Pass our instance of gorilla/mux in.
    }
    
    userDB:=new(database.User)
    userDB.Client=client
    userDB.Dbname="userdb"
    userDB.Collection="users"
    userHandler:=new(handlers.UserHandler)
    userHandler.DB=userDB
    
        //Middleware
    router.Use(middleware.WriteToConsole)
    
        //Add endpoints
    router.HandleFunc("/user/register",userHandler.Regsiter)

        srv.ListenAndServe()
}
```

middleware.go

```
func WriteToConsole(next http.Handler) http.Handler{
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
        glog.Infoln(fmt.Sprintf("%v called",r.Method))
        next.ServeHTTP(w,r)

    })
}
```

Why am i not getting the log??

Comment: The log default write the `-log_dir` files if you set. Try setting the `-logtostderr` or `-alsologtostderr` flag to force it to also log to stdout.